# How can I conditionally sum values from different columns after aggregation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe to begin with:

```
ID PRODUCT_ID        NAME  STOCK  SELL_COUNT DELIVERED_BY PRICE_A PRICE_B
1         P1  PRODUCT_P1     12          15          UPS   32,00   40,00
2         P2  PRODUCT_P2      4           3          DHL    8,00     NaN
3         P3  PRODUCT_P3    120          22          DHL     NaN  144,00
4         P1  PRODUCT_P1    423          18          UPS   98,00     NaN
5         P2  PRODUCT_P2      0           5          GLS   12,00   18,00
6         P3  PRODUCT_P3     53          10          DHL   84,00     NaN
7         P4  PRODUCT_P4     22           0          UPS    2,00     NaN
8         P1  PRODUCT_P1     94          56          GLS     NaN   49,00
9         P1  PRODUCT_P1      9          24          GLS     NaN    1,00
```

What I'm trying to achieve is - after aggregating by PRODUCT_ID, to sum PRICE_A or PRICE_B depending on whether they have a value or not (prioritizing PRICE_A if both are set).

Based on @WeNYoBen 's helping [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317598/how-do-i-conditionally-aggregate-values-in-projection-part-of-pandas-query/57317647?noredirect=1#comment101126845_57317647), I now know how to conditionally apply aggregation functions depending on different columns:

```
def custom_aggregate(grouped):

    data = {
        'STOCK': grouped.loc[grouped['DELIVERED_BY'] == 'UPS', 'STOCK'].min(),
        'TOTAL_SELL_COUNT': grouped.loc[grouped['ID'] > 6, 'SELL_COUNT'].sum(min_count=1),
        'COND_SELL_COUNT': grouped.loc[grouped['SELL_COUNT'] > 10, 'SELL_COUNT'].sum(min_count=1)
        # THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET FOGGY...
        # I somehow need to add a second condition here, that says 
        # if PRICE_B is set - use the PRICE_B value for the sum()
        'COND_PRICE': grouped.loc[grouped['PRICE_A'].notna(), 'PRICE_A'].sum()
    }

    d_series = pd.Series(data)
    return d_series

result = df_products.groupby('PRODUCT_ID').apply(custom_aggregate)
```

I really don't know if this is possible by using the .loc function. 
One way to solve this could be to create an additional column before calling .groupby that already contains the correct price values. 
But I thought there might be a more flexible way of doing this. 
I'd be happy to somehow apply a custom function for the 'COND_PRICE' value calculation that gets executed before passing the results to sum(). In SQL I could nest x levels of CASE WHEN END statements in order to implement this kind of logic. Just curious about how to implement this flexibility in pandas.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Based on your input, what'd be your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the solution we need `fillna`

```
def custom_aggregate(grouped):

    data = {
        'STOCK': grouped.loc[grouped['DELIVERED_BY'] == 'UPS', 'STOCK'].min(),
        'TOTAL_SELL_COUNT': grouped.loc[grouped['ID'] > 6, 'SELL_COUNT'].sum(min_count=1),
        'COND_SELL_COUNT': grouped.loc[grouped['SELL_COUNT'] > 10, 'SELL_COUNT'].sum(min_count=1),
        # Fillna if A have the value A return , if not check with B , both nan will keep the value as nan
        'COND_PRICE': grouped['PRICE_A'].fillna(grouped['PRICE_B']).sum()
    }

    d_series = pd.Series(data)
    return d_series
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out (again!!). 
This totally gets the requested job done. 
But could you please be so kind and give me a hint about whether it would alternatively possible to somehow apply a function to the part before sum() instead? 
You basically updated the missing values in grouped['PRICE_A']. What i'm looking for would be a function that gets `grouped` and applies different nested conditions and checks for each grouped row, in order to "build" a dynamic value for sum().

Comment: @user2549803 you can check with np.where